# `react-native run-android` fails when I pass `--deviceId`

Tags: react-native

I have a react-native project that builds fine with `react-native run-android`. But if I run it as `react-native run-android --deviceId xxxx`, I get the following error:

```
> Task :@remobile_react-native-qrcode-local-image:verifyReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':@remobile_react-native-qrcode-local-image:verifyReleaseResources'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource linking failed
  error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored not found.
  error: resource android:style/TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/colorError not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: style attribute 'android:attr/keyboardNavigationCluster' not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:7: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values-v28/values-v28.xml:11: error: resource android:attr/dialogCornerRadius not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2734: error: resource android:attr/fontStyle not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2735: error: resource android:attr/font not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2736: error: resource android:attr/fontWeight not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2737: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2738: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2902: error: resource android:attr/startX not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2905: error: resource android:attr/startY not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2908: error: resource android:attr/endX not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2911: error: resource android:attr/endY not found.
  /home/justin/BlueWallet/node_modules/@remobile/react-native-qrcode-local-image/android/build/intermediates/res/merged/release/values/values.xml:2919: error: resource android:attr/offset not found.
  error: failed linking references.
```

It's quite strange. It's as if `react-native` can't interpret static files in a QR-code library when passing a `--deviceId`. Any ideas why this might be?

[Here's the repo](https://github.com/justinmoon/BlueWallet/tree/213911904323ed15ee4815e6f7ca06e5c82dd217) if anyone is interested.